# Get senders (payers) details paypal adaptive payments IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I just about have my adaptive payments system setup. When I get my IPN notification there are no details on the person that paid.

I want to get the payers
Email
Name
Address
Phone
Country
City
State etc...

Is this possible? My current ipn responses do not give any of that information. This is all in the sandbox using a parallel payment.

Comment: you need to collect the details yourself

Comment: Thanks @Dagon. Same for all adaptive payments? Parallel and chained?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: How frustrating! Thanks for the info.

Comment: well not really its a payment gateway, its not pay-pals job to provide buyer\seller data